# Firebase .isEmailVerified returning error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble getting the user is verified function to work as it keeps returning 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'isEmailVerified' error.

Would anybody be willing to help or suggest how it can be fixed?

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!

var userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    username.delegate = self
    password.delegate = self
    self.hideKeyboardwhenTappedAround()

}

@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: username.text!, password: password.text!) { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            let loginerrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: "Please try again", preferredStyle: .alert)
            loginerrorAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(loginerrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        if user!.isEmailVerified { //value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'isEmailVerified'
            //Take user to Firebase Realtime Database
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "userLoggedIn", sender: self)
        } else {
            let notverifiedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Not verified", message: "Your account is pending verification. Please check your email and verify your account.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            notverifiedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(notverifiedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            do{
                try Auth.auth().signOut()
            } catch {
                // HANDLE ERROR
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `isEmailVerified` declared? Add the relevant code to the question by editing.

Comment: It has been added.. Thank you

Comment: Where is the declaration?

Comment: Would you mind helping me understand what do you mean that "user!.isEmailVerified {" has to be declared? Where should it be declared? 

I am very new to programming. Thank you for your help